# pd.read_excel function returns empty dataframe for xlsx sheet

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

Below script is there to convert all xlsx files placed inside the folder to CSV files with the same name.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
#set working directory
os.chdir("C:/Users/piyush.upadhyay/Piyush/Tasks/Task-61(Script to convert excel to csv)/Files")
all_files = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format('xlsx'))]
print(all_files)

li = []
for filename in all_files:
    try:
        print(filename)
        input('Going to read xlsx to csv')
        outFileName = filename.split('.')[0]+'.csv'
        data_xls = pd.read_excel(filename, engine = 'openpyxl')
        print(data_xls)
        input('Going to convert xlsx to csv')
        data_xls.to_csv(outFileName, header=True, index=None)
        input('Converted')
        
    except Exception as e:
        print ("Error Logged..")
        print(e)
        input('Enter to exit')
```

Code returns a warning at the time of reading xlsx file which says:

[image]

**Issue:** Above function returns an empty data frame when we print the data_xls variable. As soon as we save the same file manually with the same extension i.e. xlsx, the code successfully converts all excel files inside the folder into CSV files.

[image]

[Issue is same as the link describes](http://5.9.10.113/65801230/pandas-read-excel-doesnt-read-certain-xlsx-files-returns-empty-dataframe)

Comment: i don't understand 'As soon as we save the same file manually'

Comment: @LeiYang, it means -opening each excel sheet inside that folder, navigate to menu File --> Save as Excel Workbook(*.xlsx) with the same name in that folder. Run the same script and these xlsx files get converted into csvs. I've edited the question to add the screenshot

Comment: The problem is obviously related to the structure of the files so you look at these more closely with openpyxl.

Comment: can you open the original files by text editor(notepad), to check whether it is xlsx? i strongly doubt they are csv actually.